# Calling Function's return value to a script from another module?

Tags: python, function, import

I am new to the advanced problems of python. I am trying to get good if you want to make any correction it is welcomed.

I want to do run function in Run File. I can't pass the return value of a function without  altering its value.

Then assign fpath in the function firstfile.py to the secondfile.py script's sav_img variable and be able to work inside of another function.

I need to do this beacuse i can only access to the run file. When i update repo.

Run Order

Run File

```
import Firstfile
i = "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\1.jpg"
First File.file_path(i)
```

First File

```
def file_path(fpath):

      return fpath
```

Second File

```
from First File import file_path
sav_img = file_path()
print(sav_img)
```

Error on sav_img

```
TypeError: file_path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fpath'
```

sav_img = file_path.fpath doesn't working either.
I know i need to pass value but i don't want to alter its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to get the function to save the return value when called with a parameter, but return the saved value when called with none.

First File

```py
def file_path(fpath = None):
    if fpath is None:
        return file_path.fpath
    else
        file_path.fpath = fpath
        return fpath
```

Second File

```py
from FirstFile import file_path
sav_img = file_path()
print(sav_img)
```

However, this relies on the first caller never using `None` as the parameter.

Comment: nice understanding. I just tries your function is works as intended and solves my question. All i need to adjust the import order.  But it wakes 1 more question what is the best practice for this can you eleborate for me ?

Comment: This is one of a very few scenarios where a global variable makes sense. In essence `file_path.fpath` is a global variable. The function could, as an alternative, save `fpath` to a global variable and all other scripts could read that variable.

Comment: Ok nice. if u wanna see the real code of whole problem i uploaded a picture to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394163/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-variable-to-a-functions-with-an-argument-return-va

Comment: Yes, there's no need for `visualize.py` to use `file_path`. Your code should be telling your future readers (one of which could be you) that the `run1.py` module assigns a value to something and `visualize.py` needs to read that value.

Comment: I did not understand what you exactly implied. Is it that run1.py assing the image file path to global variable so visualize can use? Or in util.py i can assing to a global

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is self explanatory: your function `file_path()` requires one positional argument, named `fpath`.

You have not provided this argument when you write:

```
sav_img = file_path()
```

Hence the error.

If you want to learn more about scripts in different files, take a look at the official [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

I'm not quite sure why you define a function whose sole purpose is to return it's provided argument, I can't see why you would ever want to do that, outside of getter functions within a class that, but that is a different story.

Comment: Problem is I assing the string variable i in run.py. Then i run the function file_path(i) in run.py. I want to pass the firstfile.py fuction file_path()'s return value to as a variable to secondfile.py So i can't add any variable to the second file function all i want to assing sav_img to the return of the file_path()

Comment: @Mindtrip If you want to store data, you must store this in a variable. In this case, you could use a global variable, but this is generally considered to be bad practice. I would advise looking into Classes and Object Oriented Programming. Also, if you are running Run.py, I don't think your code in the Second File would ever run. I would strongly consider writing down, either in plain text or pseudocode, what it is you wish your code to do. Then, consider how to implement this in code.

Comment: I couldn't get the answer i want. Thanks for help but i think i couldn't explain myself clearly but i know i need to pass argument  but i don't want to alter its value from first script. If i pass and argument i will return different value which i don't want. And i can't assign to a value without passing a argument