# Is it possible to assign a variable to a function's (with an argument) return value without passing argument?

Tags: python, function, return-value

Example is especially simplified for explaining purposes.
I am trying to get better any techniques or suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

in run i am passing i variable to util.file_path and after i wanted to access in visualize.py in another function so i can assing it to sav_img then i wanna pass it to plt.savefig

Comment: But what will `fpath` and `pth` be if you don't pass something as the argument to `file_path()`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: what do you expect the value of `variable` to be? what path should be returned from `file_path()`?

Comment: i am passing "qwe" first in the first line. But i wanted to access the return value later without altering the return value @quamrana

Comment: I also can't see what the first line (with "# actually i am running this from another module") has to do with the rest?

Comment: If you have a natural default then you can make the argument `fpath` optional.

Comment: "i wanted to access the return value later without altering the return value " - then what prevents you from storing the output in a variable for later use?

Comment: purpose of the function only pass the variable in the system.  def file_path(fpath): return fpath is simplified version

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i need to use the value in another module script. i dont want to use global

Comment: @JohnColeman i dont have default value i am passing  strings in a for loop from another module with f string

Comment: "i am passing strings in a for loop" so what's stopping you from passing those as arguments to a function that needs an argument?

Comment: because i am using the return value inside of a function from another script. and this is a image recognition project i can only access make requests from main file in google colab. i can't pass variable to a fucntion to inside a function from another module on the go. @StevenRumbalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a setter/getter sort of thing.  Rather than defining a function I might suggest just using a simple container like a `dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyData:
    file_path: str

my_data = MyData("qwe")

variable = my_data.file_path  # variable is now set to "qwe"
my_data.file_path = "qwoo"
variable = my_data.file_path  # variable is now set to "qwoo"
```

Comment: "It sounds like you want a setter/getter sort of thing." Possibly true, but it seems too big a guess as a foundation for an answer.

Comment: Good idea. I dont know what setter/getter means with quick google what i understand maybe it can work i will try

Comment: This is analogous to an answer I was thinking of, but Samwise answered first.

Comment: I'm basing my inference on the comments, which make it pretty clear that OP wants to set a value with one function call and then retrieve it with another (the thing that makes it confusing is that they're trying to use the same function for both purposes, which is not generally how that sort of thing works).

Comment: @Samwise Problem starts because this is a image recognition project and i install whole repo in colab. Because of this i can make only request to main.py. I want to pass a list with fstring. I need to pass the string to inside function of a function in different module.

Comment: @Samwise I can pass the fstring to a module with function but i cannot access the return value from inside the another function in the same script

Comment: @Mindtrip You should update your question to include a sample of your code that shows where the value is being set and where it needs to be retrieved.  This is a very simple type of problem to solve but it's hard to explain without seeing some actual code.

Comment: @Samwise u can see the actual code. I uploaded as a picture

Comment: I can't copy and paste from a picture, but it doesn't look like you've made any attempt to use the method I described in my answer, so that's probably why it's not working.